# xs:int unmarshalled to null for decimal values

Tags: jaxb, jax-ws

I've got a problem related to the unmarshalling process in a JAX-WS based WebService. In WSDL file there is an element defined as

```xml
    <element name="quantity" nillable="true" type="int" />
```

In the related JAVA class it is defined as:

```java
   @XmlElement(name = "Quantity", required = true, type = Integer.class, nillable = true)
   protected Integer quantity;
```

When an XML value for this element is the representation of a decimal number (3.4), the element is unmarshalled as a null Integer. No SOAPFault is generated and it's impossible to distinguish decimal values from null values inside the WebService.
Could it be a defect in JAXB implementation or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could it be a defect in JAXB implementation or I'm doing something
>   wrong?

This is not a defect in the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation.  It is a result of how the JAX-WS is configured to use JAXB.  I will demonstrate below with an example.

**Root**

Below is a domain object with a field that matches the one from your question.  I have remove the `type=Integer.class` from the `@XmlElement` annotation since it is redundant.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(name = "Quantity", required = true, nillable = true)
    protected Integer quantity;

}
```

**Demo**

JAXB offers the ability to set a `ValidationEventHandler` on the `Unmarshaller` to give you some control over how unmarshal errors are handled.

```java
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {

            @Override
            public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
                System.out.println(event.getMessage());
                return true;
            }
        });

        StringReader xml = new StringReader("<root><Quantity>3.4</Quantity></root>");
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

In the expert group we decided that invalid element data is common and that JAXB should not fail out every time this is encountered, but you can see that a `ValidationEvent` is raised.

```xml
Not a number: 3.4
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <Quantity xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</root>
```

**Update Demo**

If we update the `ValidationEventHandler` to indicate that we do not wish to continue the `unmarshal` when a `ValidationEvent` is raised we can make the following change.

```java
        @Override
        public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
            System.out.println(event.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
```

**Updated Output**

And now the following output occurs.

```java
Not a number: 3.4
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Not a number: 3.4
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.NumberFormatException: Not a number: 3.4]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:647)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleError(UnmarshallingContext.java:676)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleError(UnmarshallingContext.java:672)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.handleParseConversionException(Loader.java:256)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.LeafPropertyLoader.text(LeafPropertyLoader.java:54)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.text(UnmarshallingContext.java:499)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.processText(SAXConnector.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.endElement(SAXConnector.java:139)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1742)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2900)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:203)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:175)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at forum14741140.Demo.main(Demo.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Not a number: 3.4
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseInt(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:101)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$17.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:713)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$17.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:711)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.parse(TransducedAccessor.java:232)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.LeafPropertyLoader.text(LeafPropertyLoader.java:50)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Blaise Doughan. I understand the example given but I'm still dealing with the problem of configure my WebService to use a custom ValidationEventHandler. The unmarshaller becomes created outside my source code and of course I can't call  unmarshaller.setEventHandler.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question in : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30617814/3632201

I have been struggling with this issue during the last week and finally i have managed a working solution. The trick is that JAXB looks for the methods beforeUnmarshal and afterUnmarshal in the object annotated with @XmlRootElement.

```
..
@XmlRootElement(name="MSEPObtenerPolizaFechaDTO")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

public class MSEPObtenerPolizaFechaDTO implements Serializable {
..

public void beforeUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent) throws JAXBException, IOException, SAXException {
        unmarshaller.setSchema(Utils.getSchemaFromContext(this.getClass()));
        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new CustomEventHandler());
  }

  public void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent) throws JAXBException {
        unmarshaller.setSchema(null);
        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(null);
  }
```

Using this ValidationEventHandler:

```
public class CustomEventHandler implements ValidationEventHandler{

      @Override
      public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
            if (event.getSeverity() == event.ERROR ||
                        event.getSeverity() == event.FATAL_ERROR)
            {
                  ValidationEventLocator locator = event.getLocator();
                  throw new RuntimeException(event.getMessage(), event.getLinkedException());
            }
            return true;
      }
}
```

}

And this is the metodh getSchemaFromContext created in your Utility class:

```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static Schema getSchemaFromContext(Class clazz) throws JAXBException, IOException, SAXException{
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
        final List<ByteArrayOutputStream> outs = new ArrayList<ByteArrayOutputStream>();
        jc.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver(){
              @Override
              public Result createOutput(String namespaceUri,
                         String suggestedFileName) throws IOException {
              ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              outs.add(out);
              StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(out);
              streamResult.setSystemId("");
              return streamResult;
              }
        });
        StreamSource[] sources = new StreamSource[outs.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < outs.size(); i++) {
              ByteArrayOutputStream out = outs.get(i);
              sources[i] = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()), "");
        }
        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        return sf.newSchema(sources);
  }
```