# Is it possible to control set-jaxb-validation-event-handler programmatically?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jax-ws, jboss7.x

In a CXF SOAP webservice, I'm using the following annotations to disable the xsd validation:

```
@EndpointProperties({ 
    @EndpointProperty(key = "set-jaxb-validation-event-handler", value = "false") 
})
```

I would like the validation to controlled at runtime (enable/disable it, based on the value of a setting retrieved from a database). My question is: is it possible to disable/enable this handler at runtime? Maybe by writing a custom event handler and not using this property at all?

Thanks.

**Edit:** an option would be not to disable the validation with `set-jaxb-validation-handler`, and rather subclass [ValidationEventHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/ValidationEventHandler.html). As explained [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html), I would then check the database setting in `handleEvent` and return according to its value.

But there are still a few downsides with this approach: first, this webservice is configured with annotations, and I can't seem to find a way to apply a `ValidationEventHandler` with annotations (same question as: [How to set custom ValidationEventHandler on JAXB unmarshaller when using annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751249/how-to-set-custom-validationeventhandler-on-jaxb-unmarshaller-when-using-annotat)).

Secondly, it means that the validation will be performed even if I don't need it; I would then lose any performance benefit.

It doesn't in fact exactly suit my needs, so I'm still open to any suggestion.

Comment: It's doable by combining Spring's `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` with disabling schema validation of your spring configuration file. What's going to be the point of being able to disable it at runtime? Are you planning to toggle validation from one request to the next?

Comment: I'm not using Spring in this application so it's not an option. No, validation won't be toggled from one request to the next, but I want it to be controllable without needing to change the code or restart the server. The easiest way to do that seems to keep a setting in a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a working solution.

As I'm running CXF on JBoss EAP 6.0, I added the following configuration to the webservices subsytem in standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
    <!-- ... -->
    <endpoint-config name="myconfig">
        <property name="set-jaxb-validation-event-handler" value="false"/>
    </endpoint-config>
    <!-- ...-->
</subsystem>
```

And the following annotation to the SEI implementation:

```
@org.jboss.ws.api.annotation.EndpointConfig(configName = "myconfig")
```

This is the related Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbossws-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

We still need a restart of the server if we want to change the property value, but it's a lesser evil.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is possible.

```
MyService service = new MyService();
MyServiceInterface port = service.getMyServicePort();
BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) port;
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(
    "set-jaxb-validation-event-handler", Boolean.FALSE);
```

Comment: This is indeed applicable to the client, but I'm looking for a server-side solution. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

For the people trying to configure that on the bus level, the following worked for me:

```
<cxf:bus id="soapClientCxfBus" bus="soapClientCxfBus" >
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="set-jaxb-validation-event-handler" value="false" />
    </cxf:properties>
</cxf:bus>
```